# PHP: Time difference in seconds

Tags: php

I would like to get the total number of seconds based from the given time, for example the following given data below:

```
$timein=04-01-2017 7:56:37 am;
$timeout=04-01-2017 5:15:17 pm;
$totalseconds= ?
```

Comment: @miken32 I think it is not. because the time is not in 24hr format

Comment: Maybe you need to look at more of the answers then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/765740)

```
<?php
$time1=strtotime("04-01-2017 7:56:37 am");
$time2=strtotime("04-01-2017 5:15:17 pm");
echo $time2-$time1;
```